# Xamarin.Forms: Plugin.Notifications not working when Sqlite-net-pcl installed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I Have a problem and I need help

when I Install Plugin.Notifications nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Notifications/5.0.0-beta3  It works good, but when I Install sqlite-net-pcl nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/   It stops working and threw this exception 
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: If you are able to catch the exception in a try catch block, that might give you some additional information where the problem is

Comment: Thank you, your hint was very help full. the problem solved.
the problem is .. sqlite-net-pcl has changed some methods in newer versions and the (Plugin.Notifications) uses the older version of sqlite-net-pcl (v 1.3.3) so I installed the the older version (v 1.3.3) and it worked.

Comment: thanks again @MichaelC.